# oracle PLSQL insert json object values by iterating over the array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert the json data i.e. by iterating over the records. but at the time insert it is throwing "ORA-40573: Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type."
Please help

```
DECLARE
  l_obj         JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_emp_arr     JSON_ARRAY_T;
  l_emp_obj     JSON_OBJECT_T;
  PROCEDURE display (
            p_obj       IN      JSON_OBJECT_T,
            p_resp  OUT     JSON_OBJECT_T) IS
  BEGIN
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(p_obj.stringify);
    
    l_emp_arr := p_obj.get_array('items');
    FOR i IN 0 .. l_emp_arr.get_size - 1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('-------------------------------------------');
    l_emp_obj := TREAT(l_emp_arr.get(i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
    
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_TBL1 (EMP_ID, NAME, SALARY) VALUES (l_emp_obj.get_number('empid'), l_emp_obj.get_string('name'), l_emp_obj.get_number('salary'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('index           : ' || i);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('department_name : ' || l_emp_obj.get_string('name'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('department_no   : ' || l_emp_obj.get_number('salary'));
  END LOOP;
    
    p_resp := p_obj;
  END;
BEGIN
  -- Create a new object.
  display(JSON_OBJECT_T('{"supplier":"name","items":[{"empid":109, "name":"raj","salary":111},{"empid":110, "name":"raj1","salary":222}] }'), l_obj);
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_obj.get_string('supplier'));
END;
```

below is the create table

```
CREATE TABLE
        EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_TBL
        (
                EMP_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                NAME   VARCHAR2(50)               ,
                SALARY NUMBER
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use PL/SQL or objects or loops and, instead, can do it in a single `INSERT` statement using `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
INSERT INTO employee_detail_tbl (emp_id, name, salary)
SELECT empid, name, salary
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{"supplier":"name","items":[{"empid":109, "name":"raj","salary":111},{"empid":110, "name":"raj1","salary":222}] }',
         '$.items[*]'
         COLUMNS(
           empid  NUMBER       PATH '$.empid',
           name   VARCHAR2(50) PATH '$.name',
           salary NUMBER       PATH '$.salary'
         )
       );
```

Which, after the `INSERT`, the table contains:

| EMP_ID | NAME | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 109 | raj | 111 |
| 110 | raj1 | 222 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UjPiTrR-)

Answer (score 1):

The complete error you get is:

```
40573. 00000 -  "Invalid use of PL/SQL JSON object type."
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a PL/SQL JavaScript Object Notation
           (JSON) object type in an invalid context.
*Action:   Use PL/SQL JSON object types only inside PL/SQL.
```

So the solution is to extract the values in the PL/SQL context before given them to the SQL one:

```
DECLARE
  l_obj         JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_emp_arr     JSON_ARRAY_T;
  l_emp_obj     JSON_OBJECT_T;
  
  l_empid EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_TBL.EMP_ID%TYPE;
  l_name EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_TBL.NAME%TYPE;
  l_salary EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_TBL.SALARY%TYPE;
  
  PROCEDURE display (
            p_obj       IN      JSON_OBJECT_T,
            p_resp  OUT     JSON_OBJECT_T) IS
  BEGIN
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(p_obj.stringify);
    
    l_emp_arr := p_obj.get_array('items');
    FOR i IN 0 .. l_emp_arr.get_size - 1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('-------------------------------------------');
    l_emp_obj := TREAT(l_emp_arr.get(i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
    
    l_empid := l_emp_obj.get_number('empid');
    l_name := l_emp_obj.get_string('name');
    l_salary := l_emp_obj.get_number('salary');
    
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_TBL (EMP_ID, NAME, SALARY) VALUES (l_empid, l_name, l_salary);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('index           : ' || i);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('department_name : ' || l_emp_obj.get_string('name'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('department_no   : ' || l_emp_obj.get_number('salary'));
  END LOOP;
    
    p_resp := p_obj;
  END;
BEGIN
  -- Create a new object.
  display(JSON_OBJECT_T('{"supplier":"name","items":[{"empid":109, "name":"raj","salary":111},{"empid":110, "name":"raj1","salary":222}] }'), l_obj);
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_obj.get_string('supplier'));
END;
```